# downloadLink issue in firebase storage flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies

When I use firebase storage in flutter I got an issue of "_downloadLink" that says ""the declaration _downlaodLink isn't referenced"". How I solve this?? please help me on this.

```
  Future<void> _downloadLink(firebase_storage.Reference ref) async {
    final link = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
      text: link,
    ));
```